# modrewrite in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just wanted to know if is possible to use `mod_rewrite` on a single(or more ) sub folder(s).
have a service in a folder that i would like to call like a rest service syntax .

```
$url = 'http://mysite/subfolder/parem1/parem2/parem3/';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

$tokens = explode('/', $url);
echo $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-2];
```

so the question is if I could catch all the different segments in a index.php in the subfolder, by using forexample modrewrite ( by placing a `.htaccess` with the rules only in this folder ? ) or how is it done ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. In your .htaccess, you could put something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$                               index.php?p1=$1
    RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$                     index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2
    RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$           index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3
    RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4

</IfModule>
```

In your case you could just put the .htaccess file with the index.php in the folder where your service is located.

This way you can fetch (and sanitize) the `$_GET` array, instead of fetching the whole url.

Comment: Is it possible to also "hide" the index.php when writing or linking to the url .. if I write myfolder/param1/param2 at the momment it says that the folder does not exsist .. perhaps I did something wrong ?

Comment: At this point, index.php should be already hidden from url. Maybe you have other rules in another .htaccess in the main folder?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define rewriting rules for a subfolder, take a look at [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /yoursubfolder
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$param=$1
</IfModule>
```